# systemctl failed restart due to permission issue

Tags: redis, systemctl

I installed redis and put redis-server at /usr/local/bin:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 redis         redis         11044232 Sep 24 00:30 redis-server
```

I have redis.conf in the same folder /usr/local/bin:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 redis         redis              120 Oct  6 21:30 redis.conf
```

I created redis.service at /etc/systemd/system:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  192 Oct  6 21:46  redis.service
```

cat redis.conf:

```
Description=Redis
After=network.target
[Service]
User=redis
Group=redis
Type=Simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /usr/local/bin/redis.conf
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

but when I run

```
sudo systemctl restart redis
sudo systemctl status redis
```

it showed: Can't open the append-only file: Permission denied

if I change user and group in service unit to "root" at redis.service and restart again the redis server is successfully started.

I did add the user redis:

```
sudo useradd --no-create-home --shell /bin/false redis
```

what is the reason? I want to use dedicated user redis to start the server.

Answer (score 0):

**Cause**

User `redis` does not have user permission to access `/usr/local/bin/appendonly.aof` because it is in `/usr/local/bin`.

By default the Redis working directory is relative to `redis.conf`, as set by the line:

```
dir ./
```

**Solution**

1. Either change `dir ./` in the `redis.conf` to a directory writable by the `redis` user
2. Or put the `redis.conf` in a directory writable by the `redis` user (only executable files should reside in `/usr/local/bin` anyway)

Comment: Thanks for answering me. in fact the redis.conf was originally in another directory  /home/myname/cluster_test/ and its user/group are both redis. it did not work that is why I move it to  /usr/local/bin but it still did not work. what does dir ./ mean?

Comment: @user389955 `dir ./` refers to the redis.conf line where you can configure the working directory, e.g. `dir /var/redis/` would configure redis to put `appendonly.aof` and `redis.rdb` in the `/var/redis/` directory - you must ensure that the `redis` user can list, read and write to that directory by doing `chmod 700 redis` (gives user redis all permissions and none to all else).